# How to make sure that a child process of a supervisor job dies when I kill supervisor

Tags: shell, process, supervisord

My app is a jar file that requires some environment variables. I have all the environment variables in one file, which looks like this:

```
export VAR=value
export VAR2=value2
#....etc
```

My supervisor config file looks like this:

```
[program:programname]
command=bash -c "source /path/to/env/file && java -jar /path/to/jar.jar"
```

`ps -ef | grep programname` shows two processes on two separate lines: one is `bash -c "source blah && java blah"` and the other one is just `java blah`.

Now, here's the problem: whether I do `supervisorctl stop programname` or `service supervisor stop` or even `kill -9 whatever the supervisor pid is`, the first process dies, but the regular java process stays and becomes orphaned, with parent pid now 1. How do I make the jar die without manually killing it?

Comment: Try adding `killasgroup=true`. (and `stopasgroup=true` if you wish).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `exec` to replace `bash` with `java`:

```
[program:programname]
command=bash -c "source /path/to/env/file && exec java -jar /path/to/jar.jar"
```

In such a case you will have only one process to kill.

Comment: This works too, and requires less changes than the other comment. Granted if I kill -9 the supervisor daemon itself it still leaves the jar running, but that's just what happens when you murder a process like that with no warning.

Answer (score 2):

Make the command instead a shell script that replaces itself with the java?

```
#!/bin/bash
source /i/pity/da/env/foo
exec java ...
```

Comment: It's working! I'll wait for a day or two before accepting, though, since this is the first answer.